# Converting C to Actionscript 3?

Tags: c, actionscript-3

Can anyone point me to online tutorials, parsing apps, etc for converting C code into actionscript3?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you take a look at [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Alchemy:FAQ) by Adobe, a mostly automatic way to translate C/C++ applications.

Comment: Thanks, I'm more interested in manual conversion from existing C libraries.

Comment: @eco: If the C code uses anything beyond the most basic features, then you're in for a world of hurt.  Macros, typedefs, uninions, direct memory manipulation, function overloading, etc.  It sounds like you should check out Alchemy as Kaleb suggests.